# solr 4.8 with tomcat - when running zkcli.sh i get "Packet len1213486160 is out of range"

Tags: tomcat, solr, centos, apache-zookeeper

I'm installing solr and tomcat on amazon machine (centos 6).
Solr is up and running on port 8983 as I ran `java -jar start.jar` from `/opt/solr/shard1`.

I did edit all the configuration files and changed the owner of `/opt/solr` to tomcat user and the service is running on port 8983.

I enabled tomcat and restarted it using `/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh & service tomcat restart`

But when running:

```
cd /opt/solr/shard1/ & scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -cmd bootstrap -zkhost localhost:8983 -solrhome solr
```

I get a java exception as follows:

> org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread; Session 0x0 for server localhost/127.0.0.1:8983, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
>   java.io.IOException: Packet len1213486160 is out of range!

Answer (score 0):

The embedded zookeeper doesn't live on the same port as Solr. [It usually lives on <solrport>+1000](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud).

> -DzkHost=localhost:9983 points to the Zookeeper ensemble containing the cluster state. In this example we're running a single Zookeeper server embedded in the first Solr server. By default, an embedded Zookeeper server runs at the Solr port plus 1000, so 9983.

If this is a fresh setup you should however consider 1) to upgrade to the most recent version of Solr, and 2) Drop Tomcat, as using Solr as a .war isn't supported any longer. If you can't drop Tomcat, the most recent version of Solr 4.x is at least recommended.

Comment: I have `9983` as default port.

Comment: But you're giving `8983` in your `zkcli` command: `-zkhost localhost:8983`